# Unable to compile .netcore project with framework 1.1

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created .netcore project that works fine with TargetFramework = 2.0. I want to downgrade it to version 1.1 but I am getting

> Error NU1102  Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR
>   with version (>= 1.1.2)   - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 1.0.2 ]
>     - Found 0 version(s) in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder

4 other package are missing. 
I tried to install those missing package with nuget but I got errors. 
 I tried this downgrade on an empty .netcore console app project but I got the same errors. I wonder if this downgrade is possible

Comment: 1.1 isn't mature enough to use IMO. Why do you want to downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the target framework doesn't really work, I guess. Did you try to also use the 1.1 SDK, by changing/adding the global.json in your solution?